# Oracle APEX Report - Merge same cells

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is there any way to merge cells with the same value using Oracle APEX Interactive Grid/Report?

Instead of showing data like this:

[image]

I'd like to have a report with merged cells:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Apex can't do that itself, out of the box.

What it does offer is *break*. Interactive report and grid don't do it as you want (break columns are listed "above" the rest of the report; they are set in the "Actions" menu), so the most similar layout you'd want to get offers **classic report** with - as I said - break being set:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Named Column (Row Template) to merge cells with with *classic* reports

https://blog.eberapp.com/ords/f?p=BLOG:READ:::::ARTICLE:5976400346831048&cs=1381D760A2B9B744DB8C2612E5494D7D7

You can use the Detail view in *Interactive Reports* to do a similar thing, but you'll quickly lose native column features.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6AKNGbSVwQ

If you attempted to do this with editable *Interactive Grids*, you would lose the context required to allow columns to be updateable.